# How to change the dns of a running docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker

the default dns 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are blocked by my nation's firewall, and I do not want to stop the container for I install a lot of software in it.

Comment: I feel you have somehow missed at least half the point and utility of containers if you can't stop and re-run it. Between Dockerfiles to generate new base images with any static changes you need, and volumes to persist dynamic data, well, my starting point would be there.

Comment: I agree that having installed a lot of software is a bad reason.  However, when I am 20 minutes into reproducing a twenty-something minute CI failure and I want to update something and redo an incremental test, it would be really nice to set DNS, download a package (need DNS to do that easily), and continue.  I can just restart it, and wait those extra 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the DNS, you can just do it in the same way you would on a normal host and this should just work. For example editing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file in the container.

Although if it is entirely blocked, I'd recommend a more permanent solution.

In `/etc/default/docker` (may be `/etc/default/docker.io` on Debian based hosts) you can add a line to set the default DNS on new containers. This line would look something like

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4"
```

You can just add  a new `-dns x.x.x.x` for every DNS server you wish to use to resolve.

Once you have done this you will need to restart the Docker process. This is done in a few ways depending on the host again. For Debian based hosts:

```
 service docker.io restart
```

When you `docker run` a new container, it will have those DNS servers set.

Comment: This will obviously restart a container. Moreover this won't change container settings, they stick when  container is created.

Comment: This will not change DNS settings of an already running container

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf is a mount from docker itself so it can manage container DNS. The file is not writable and cant be updated from within the container.